# How to show my Array in Text without Repetition using AS3?

Tags: actionscript-3

```
var arr:Array = new Array("A","B","C")
        //random number
        var rand:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*arr.length)
        //my text 
        t1.text = arr[rand]
        t2.text = arr[rand]
        t3.text = arr[rand]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like

```
private function getRandomText():String
{
    var rand:Number = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);

    // this will both get you the random string from the array 
    // and remove it from the array making sure you won't get the same text next time
    var randomString:String = arr.splice(rand, 1);

    return randomString;
}

t1.text = getRandomText();
t2.text = getRandomText();
t3.text = getRandomText();
```

Naturally, this will modify the array by removing the displayed string. So if you need to keep the array for the future use you'd need to make a copy of that and use the copy

Answer (score 1):

At my opinion, you may use this kind of function.
This was quick done but I think that avoid to check everytime in a do while loop (useless and slower).
So you may easily change the code as you need it...

```
var choices:Vector.<String> = new <String>["A","B","C","D","E","F"];
var randomChoices:Vector.<String> = new Vector.<String>();
var choicesBackup:Vector.<String>;

function populateLetters():void{
    var n: uint = Math.floor(Math.random()*choices.length);
    randomChoices.push(choices[n]);
    choices.splice(n,1);
}

function getDifferentLetters():Vector.<String>{
    choicesBackup = choices.slice();
    randomChoices = new Vector.<String>();
    for(var i:uint=choices.length; i>0; i--){
        populateLetters();
    }
    choices = choicesBackup.slice();
    return randomChoices;
}


trace ("letters = " + choices + ", flush = " + getDifferentLetters());

// output : letters = A,B,C,D,E,F, flush = D,E,B,C,F,A
```

Comment: how to show my array in text  T1.text = populateLetters() not working

Answer (score 0):

If I missed something, just let me know!

```
T1.text = getDifferentLetters();
```

etc...
Example :

```
var t1:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(t1);
t1.text = getDifferentLetters().toString();
t1.x = 100;
t1.y = 100;

var t2:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(t2);
t2.text = getDifferentLetters().toString();
t2.x = 100;
t2.y = 150;

var t3:TextField = new TextField();
addChild(t3);
t3.text = getDifferentLetters().toString();
t3.x = 100;
t3.y = 200;
```

This should work if you have a reference to your variable T1.
In your code try to use "Lowercase" for your variables and methods.
"Uppercase" for the first letter of classes and all in "uppercase" if you use a constant.

**If you use only Strings in an Array, use Vector.<String> instead of Array!**

trace was just an example to get the result in the output.
Best regards.
Nicolas.

Comment: Please @ActionScript student uppvote or downvote or mark the answer as "Solved" if the answer is right!
If you need more information, or face another issue, edit your question!

Comment: nothig new .its same problrm . I have 3 TextField on stage ALL Letter show in 3 text same time

Comment: I want removing the displayed string from array dont show again

Comment: as @Philarmon  told you, you have to keep the array for the future use you'd need to make a copy of that and use the copy...
And override the result of randomChoices

Comment: its same problem my text1 show ABCDEF my texts show ABCDEF my text3 show ABCDEF ...I want evey text show one letter without repetition

Comment: And so far do you still have an issue now? Consider the answer of @Philarmon
And don't forget what I said : So you may easily change the code as you need it...
It's a quick done answer, so you need to change the code.

Comment: @ActionScriptstudent I changed the code.
The reason why you had always the same result was because once the method was called without backing up choices, the Vector was empty.
As I told you, a backup was needed.